Prove that the set $A = \{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^{2} : y > x^{2}\}$ is connected
Prove that the set $A = \{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^{2} : y > x^{2}\}$ is connected.
Intuitively A consists of the points above the graph of the map $x \mapsto x^{2} $ so my guess is that it´s convex and in particular it´s connected. To show it is convex, let $(a, b), (c, d) \in A$ and pick $(x, y) \in [(a, b), (c, d)]$. There exists some $t \in (0, 1)$ such that
$$
(x, y) = (1-t)(a,b) + t(c,d)
$$
which gives $x = (1-t)a + t c,\ y = (1-t)b + td$.  Note that $a^{2} < b,\ c^{2} < d$. Therefore
$$
x^{2} = (1-t)^{2}a^{2} + 2t(1-t)ac + t^{2}c^{2} < (1-t)^{2}b + 2t(1-t)ac + t^{2}d < (1-t)b + 2ac + td
$$
From here I´m stuck because I just get nonsense. Where´s the mistake? Is there any other argument that I could use to show $A$ is connected?

You have to get rid of $ac$ also by noting that $a<\sqrt b$ and $c <\sqrt d$.

@geetha290krm That would introduce $\sqrt{bd}$ which could be greater than $bd$

@jjagmath I am not saying that those two inequalities give the complete answer. Far from that.  There is a lot of Calculus work to be done.

A different proof would be to use the homeomorphism $(x, y) \mapsto (x, y - x^2)$ which takes $A$ to $\mathbb{R} \times (0, \infty)$.

For any strictly convex function $f$, ${(x,y): y>f(x)}$ is convex and this is immemdiate from definition. You just have to note that $x^{2}$ is  strictly convex.

@geetha290krm "immediately from the definition"?

Yes, just write the definition of strict convexity. @jjagmath

@geetha290krm The definition involves a segment joining two points of the form $(x,f(x))$, but you don't have that.

@ronno You could simplify a little if you take $(x, y) \mapsto (x, y + x^2)$ from $\Bbb R\times (0,\infty)$ to $A$. Then you don't need to prove it's a homeomorphism, only a continuous function whose image is $A$.

Following your proof, we arrive at
$$x^2 = (1-t)^2a^2 + 2t(1-t)ac + t^2 c^2$$
and here, you jump the gun too fast. Often, it is a good idea to save estimates for as late as possible to avoid "losing too much information". So sticking with equalities, we have
$$\begin{align*}
x^2 - y &= (1-t)^2a^2 + 2t(1-t)ac + t^2c^2 - (1-t)b - td\\
&= (1-t) (a^2 - b) + t(c^2 - d) - t(1-t)a^2 - t(1-t)c^2 + 2t(1-t)ac\\
&= (1-t)(a^2 - b) + t (c^2 -d) - t(1-t)(a^2 - 2ac + c^2)\\
& = \underbrace{(1-t) (a^2 - b)}_{<0} + \underbrace{t(c^2 - d)}_{<0} + \underbrace{-t(1-t)(a-c)^2}_{<0}
\end{align*}
$$
Also, you did not choose the easiest way to prove connectedness, [edit : this is the same idea as psl2Z's answer]. If $(a,b)$ and $(c,d)$ are in $A$, then join them with three segments : two vertical segments going to some high enough $y$-coordinate $Y$, and one horizontal segment joining these. The vertical segments will obviously stay in $A$, and the horizontal segment stays in $A$ when $Y > 1 + \max(a,b)^2$, because for all $x \in [\min(a,b),\max(a,b)]$, $x^2 < Y$.
[Edit: as pointed out in other comments, one concludes using the result that path-connected $\implies$ connected, see e.g. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2417538/path-connectedness-implies-connectedness]

For every continuous $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ the set
$$C=\{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 \ | \ y > f(x)\}$$
is connected, even path-connected.
To see this let $(x_0,y_0),(x_1,y_1) \in C$. Let
$$h_{\varepsilon} := \varepsilon + \max_{x\in[x_0,x_1]} f(x)$$
for some $\varepsilon > 0$. Define paths
$$\gamma_i: [0,1] \to C, \ t \mapsto (x_i,th_{\varepsilon} + (1-t)y_i)$$
for $i = 0,1$ and
$$\gamma_h: [0,1] \to C, \ t \mapsto ((1-t)x_0 + tx_1, h_\varepsilon).$$
Then define the path $\gamma := \gamma_0\gamma_h \bar \gamma_1: [0,1] \to C$ (path composition), where $\bar \gamma_1$ is the inverse path. Then $\gamma(0) = \gamma_0(0) = (x_0,y_0)$ and $\gamma(1) = \bar \gamma_1(1) = \gamma_1(0) = (x_1,y_1)$. Thus $\gamma$ is a path from $(x_0,y_0)$ to $(x_1,y_1)$.
Now set $f(x) = x^2$ for $x \in \mathbb{R}$.

It holds also for arbitrary functions which are bounded on compact intervals with the same proof.

The space $C$ is even contractible (if $f$ is continuous). To see this define $\Psi: \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^2, \ (x,y) \mapsto (x,y-f(x))$ and $\Phi: \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^2, \ (x,y) \mapsto (x,y+f(x))$. Then $\Psi$ is a homeomorphism with $\Phi = \Psi^{-1}$ and $\Psi(C) = \mathbb{R}\times (0,\infty)$ which is contractible.

Why did somebody downvote?

My guess is that it's because you are not answering the question as asked, which was "From here I´m stuck because I just get nonsense. Where´s the mistake?" You are simply giving a different proof. (Personally, I don't think it should have been downvoted, since someone besides OP using MSE could find it useful.)

@user43208 Yes, but the OP asked also "Is there any other argument that I could use to show A is connected?". Anyway...

That is true. Here's an upvote to balance the score.

Why not choose $\epsilon = 1$ and avoid some notational baggage?

We have $A=\{(x,y)\in\Bbb R^2\mid y> f(x)\}$ where $f$ is a convex function.
Let $(a,b)$ and $(c,d)$ two points in $A$ and $(x,y)=(1-t)(a,b)+t(c,d)$ with $t\in [0,1]$.
Then $b>f(a)$, $d>f(c)$, $x=(1-t)a+tc$ and $y=(1-t)b+td$
We have $y=(1-t)b+td>(1-t)f(a)+t f(c)\ge f((1-t)a+tc)=f(x)$ so $(x,y)\in A$ which proves that $A$ is convex.

Okay, but  then it has to shown that $f(x) = x^2$ is a convex function. This results in the same "problem" as in the question.

@PaulFrost $f''(x)=2>0$

Of course. But you invoke a non-trivial (though standard) theorem. At least you should explicitly mention it in your question.

@PaulFrost Other answers here are using the fact that a convex set or a path-connected space are connected. Why aren't you also demanding them to explicitly mention those theorems?
